# Schedule a downtime for NiFi flow at the end of the day

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a Nifi flow which reads data from a Kafka queue, splits the message into 2 different components and then writes it to 2 different locations in HDFS.
I want to schedule a downtime for 15 minutes at the end of the day (11:45pm to 12:00am) which could allow all the messages already split to be drained from the queues and landed to the respective HDFS locations on the same day.
Is there a way to get this done?

I have tried looking at the wait processor. I can schedule the processor to start at a certain time but I'm unable to identify how to stop the processor after 12:00am.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of implementation options I can think of,

- NiFi REST API call to stop-start the required processor
- Routing - check current timestamp is between 11:45pm and 12:00am and route such FlowFiles to `LogAttribute` with Run Schedule every 15 mins.